# Open app in current directory when another app with the same name exists, from command line

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I have an app name `foo.app` I want to open from command line (using `open`).

My folder structure is like this:

```
~
+---bar
     +--- foo.app
+---baz
     +--- foo.app
```

I want to open the app located in the `bar` folder, however if I do `open -a foo.app`, the app located in the `baz` folder will open, even if my current working directory is in the `bar` folder.

`open -a ./foo.app` or `open -a ~/bar/foo.app` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `open -a` is **NOT** what you want; the `-a` option is for launching known applications (indexed in the Launch Services database that lets you open a document and get the right application) by name, not by pathname, or for opening files with a given application.

What you are looking for is just plain **opening** `foo.app`, just like you double-clicked it in the Finder. To do that,

```
open foo.app
```

This will open exactly that application, without involving the Launch Services database at all.

Answer (score 0):

> open bar/foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo

If you're using the -a parameter to `open`, then you need to omit the .app extension.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I omit the .app extension and what if the executable is not named foo? How would I get the executable name? Example :`bar/foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foobar`

Comment: Typically the .app bundle and the actual executable file (in the Contents/MacOS/ directory) have the same name. So if the top-level directory is named foo.app, I would expect the executable file to be foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo .

Comment: But in this case it doesn't...

Comment: Then you will need to go into the .app directory and determine the name of the executable file in order to type the correct `open` command. How did you obtain these apps?

Comment: It's a jar bundled inside an app so the executable name is actually `JavaApplicationStub`. I also found out that the executable name is stored in the Info.plist as `CFBundleExecutable`.

Comment: Ah, well I recommend you write questions using the actual data whenever possible. Sometimes, fictional examples can get in the way of getting the problem solved.